# Не отображается текстура в приложении

Tags: android, libgdx

В процессе изучения фреймворка libgdx я нашел замечательный способ структурировать проект.
И вот мой пример реализации загрузки текстуры и ее отображение.

Реализуем Синглтон Ассетменеджера

```
public class GameAsssetManager extends AssetManager {

private static GameAsssetManager instance;

public static GameAsssetManager getInstance(){
    if(null == instance)
        instance = new GameAsssetManager();

    return instance;
}

public void init(){}
}
```

Вот код экрана загрузки, где **текстура загружается**:

```
public class LoadScreen implements Screen{

private void loadAssets(){
    GameAsssetManager.getInstance().load("badlogic.jpg",Texture.class);
}

@Override
public void show() {
    GameAsssetManager.getInstance().init();
    loadAssets();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    //Метод update возвращает true в том случаи, если все ресурсы загружены
    if(GameAsssetManager.getInstance().update()){
        ScreenManager.getInstance().show(CustomScreen.GAME);
    }
}
***
}
```

Ну и собственно **отображение**

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
...
@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    texture = GameAsssetManager.getInstance().get("badlogic.jpg");
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(
            texture,
            Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 - texture.getWidth()/2,
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - texture.getHeight()/2
    );
    batch.end();
}
...
```

Использую AndroidStudio, тестирую приложение на разных гаджетах, что найду в общаге.

Так вот проблема в следующем.
При компиляции приложения всё работает отлично, текстуру видно.
Но если запустить установленное приложение, то на том месте, где должна быть текстура, - чёрных квадрат.

Comment: Не мог бы ли ты пожалуйста выложить код с твоим решением, у меня тоже такая проблема, но что именно делать надо я не понял, буду очень признателен.
При assetmanager.dispose() он же уничтожается, получается надо заново весь атлас подгрузить при возвращении в приложение?
И где тогда в данном случае что прописывать?(подгружать?)

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял, в чём дело, после того как перезагрузил планшет. После выхода из программы класс Синглтона (или одиночка) остается в памяти, и Андроид имеет свойство освобождать GLContent после паузы или закрытия активити, как описано  [здесь](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1073).

И проблема вот в чем. Закрывал я приложение, синглтон ассетменеджера оставался в памяти, но терял GLContent. И когда я открывал приложение снова, мое приложение обращалось к классу, который был создан в предыдущем запуске.

Проблема решилась добавлением dispose() метода и его вызов в соответствующем методе интерфейса Screen.